# “Invalid JWT: Failed audience check.” Error when trying to get OAuth Token from Google using the service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-api, jwt, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to get an OAuth2 token from google and keep getting this response:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Invalid JWT: Failed audience check. The right audience is https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&amp;assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJqb2Jpbmppc21pQGluZGlhLW5ldHN1aXRlLmlhbS5nc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQuY29tIiwic3ViIjoiaWxzZS5wcmFra2VuQHpvbm5lcGFuZaaaJzY29wZSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lmdvb2dsZWFwaXMuY29tL2F1dGgvY2FsZW5kYXIiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL29hdXRoMi5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS90b2tlbiIsImV4cCI6MTYxNTQ2MTU1OSwiaWF0IjoxNjE1NDU3OTU5fQ.HQ2nhaaaiB9b6jMq4l"
}
```

I need to access the google calendar API without user consent, so I have used the service account. I need to use the service account on the behalf of the application. I have given G Suite domain-wide authority to the service account for that I have Delegated domain-wide authority to the service account.

I followed  all the steps defined in the google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest)

When I try to get an access token, I am getting an error. The error is

> invalid grant: Invalid JWT: Failed audience check.

I am sending the request using the Postman:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUaaaIsInRIkpXVCIsImtpZCI6ImNkNjcwMzg4YzNhNjJiODBkZWJiNGQ2NmNiMzhiMDdhZDc5YjI0OWQifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJqd3Qtc2VydmljZS1hY2NvdW50QGp3dC1mb3ItY2FsZW5kYXIuaWFtLmdzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VaaaaaaiJmZWJpbkBqb2JpbmFuZGppc21pLmNvR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlYXBpcy5jb20vYXV0aC9jYWxlbmRhciIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vb2F1dGgyLmdvb2dsZWFwaXMaaaaNjE1NDY3NTcxLCJpYXjE2MTU0NjM5NzF9.NYwUaaaapxGmCWkUuEJurPWu5-vTrEpcL16g3lut8Z23p0R_jxOZZrYDA5lwDEjkqN0xxthvye7XBhvkpwRIn6kkydtw2p142O3aMczuK0wRV1RQmhO37oerKMPpZB8gpJf9RAL4BBNHx_CUgu4PN5TIaVw1raGWOoyfrwUnHyU8MFMHIfIBcm0h34GF9NfvBddSAfKPPqM0KsAZth4BHDa1ZYuYwXfRKQuJUZX1qpl6_z7Zlhl3Np4KShIvGaIAtd6OHR4EWDnV4pfzSDYy_JjCxRSbJ6-UDUKR86dLHuvpRlvMbrzJ07Gms47A' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Does anyone know what might be causing my audience check to fail and what I should be using as that value? Does anyone know where I am wrong for accessing the access token?

Comment: Show the JWT that you created in your question. The audience is the `aud` key in the payload. In my code, I use the value `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token`.

Comment: Edit your question with the new details.

Comment: I have seen some similar issues that were resolved changing hte BASE64 encoder.
Can you specify which are using and try another one?